# XML invalid enumeration

Tags: xml, enumeration

So I am getting this annoying error when writing XML. Error description:

*cvc-enumeration-valid: Value ' First ' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[First, Second]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.*

Schema

```
    <xs:simpleType name="std-semester">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="First"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Second"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

As you see values from enumeration are First and Second but still giving me error mentioned above even I put correct value "First". What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trailing space in "First " is significant. If you want to treat leading and trailing space as insignificant, use type xs:NMTOKEN rather than xs:string.